# how can I creates a mysqli database for first the first time?

Tags: php, mysqli

I was running an example from a [mysqli tutorial](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php).

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database");
if($mysqli->connect_errno)
{
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ) "
  . $mysqli->connect_error;} echo $mysqli->host_info . "\n";
}
```

I was getting the error:

> Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (42000/1049): Unknown database 'world' in /home/...

What should I do to create the database?

Comment: Connect to `MySQL` and issue `CREATE DATABASE world`.

Comment: how can i do the right with the oop mysqli interface?

Comment: answer! it need creates to console

Answer (score 2):

You have to use this:

```
$mysqli=new mysqli("localhost","user","password") or die(".........");

if($mysqli->query("Create database if not exists MyDB")){

   "Failed creating new database: ".$mysqli->connect_errno();
    die();

}

$mysqli->select_db("MyDB");
$mysqli->close();
```

Answer (score 1):

try something like this

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password");
```

in this way you are connected to database

and put this query using `mysqli` `Create Database database1`

Comment: I create database trough mysql query broser and after connection to database.