# How do I execute SQL syntax properly using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

Using PHP and MYSQLI I want to do an automatic database setup.
I have the SQL syntax but I don't know how to use them in php.
how do I execute this syntax?

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS `mydb`
CREATE DATABASE `mydb` CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
CREATE TABLE `receipt` (`id` int(255) NOT NULL ...)
```

Can I do this? and if I can, do I need to be connected to a certain database?

## Update

The closes thing I can think off is this

```
$connection->query("DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS mydb;....");
```

but this is wrong because it needs connection to a database !!! how I am I suppose to create a database if I need another database to run the query !!

## Update

This is what I needed to do

```
$connection= new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
$connection->query("DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS `mydb`;CREATE DATABASE `mydb` CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;");
$connection->close();
$connection= new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, 'mydb');
$connection->query("CREATE TABLE `receipt` (`id` int(255) NOT NULL);");
```

Comment: Did you try? What did your syntax look like? Did you get an errors? If so, what did the errors say?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I don't know how to run it, the closes thing I can think off is this $connection->query("DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS `mydb`;....");, but this is wrong because it needs connection to a database !!!

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10781440/how-can-i-creates-a-mysqli-database-for-first-the-first-time. Also with your query I think you'll need multi-query because I think the drop and create are separate queries.

Comment: You need to create a database.  If you're on a web host there will be tools in their control panel to create a database.

Comment: @chris85 check Reference 1 please!

Comment: @efru I want the process of creating a database to be automatic, if I created the database manually that's not automatic anymore !

Comment: I don't know I would try it and see. I think you need to use multi-query though. I'd also not close the connection but just select the new db that was created.

Comment: @chris85 I've just tried it and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can execute that in PHP using MySQLI.  Here's a simple sample to connect :

```
$connection = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'database_name');
$query = $connection->query("YOUR QUERY HERE");
```

This will create a connection to a database on the machine, then $query will store the resulting object of the query.  If the database you're looking to query is on another server, you'll have to change localhost to whatever ip/port that that database is on.

Hope this helps.

Comment: But this needs connection to a database !!! How am I suppose to create a database for the site if I am in need to a database to run the query?

Comment: @zakaria The 4th argument is optional, you do not have to provide a database.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Thanks, that what was troubling me out.